# ENOTFOUND Error while using aws-sdk/client-s3

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I am writing code to get file data from AWS S3. while doing so, I am trying to use latest AWS SDK V3. The npm SDK @aws-sdk/client-s3 giving me Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND code. But if I use V2 of same SDK the code runs smoothly and give proper response.

@aws-sdk/client-s3 Code

```
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');

const sslCertificate = createReadStream('./securityCert.pem');

const s3 = new S3Client({
  endpoint: 'https://customeUrl.dummy.net',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  service: 's3',
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY',
    secretAccessKey: 'SECURITY_KEY'
  },
  tls: {
    ca: sslCertificate
  },
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
  s3ForcePathStyle: true,

});

const bucketName = 'bucket_name';
const objectKey = 's3upload123.txt';

const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: objectKey
});

s3.send(getObjectCommand)
  .then(data => {
    console.log("data", data.Body.toString());
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Above code give me error. But below code runs properly.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require('https');
const sslCertificate = fs.readFileSync('./securityCert.pem');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
//   signatureVersion: 'v4',
//   region: "us-east-1",
  accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY',
  secretAccessKey: 'SECURITY_KEY',
  endpoint: `https://customeUrl.dummy.net`,
  s3ForcePathStyle: true,
  httpOptions: {
    agent: new https.Agent({
      ca: sslCertificate
    })
  }
});

const bucketName = 'bucket_name';
const objectKey = 's3upload123.txt';

const getObjectParams = {
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: objectKey
};

s3.getObject(getObjectParams, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log("data", data.Body.toString());
  }
});
```

I tried running both the code with nodejs to give me same result.

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in your endpoint url?

Comment: @derpirscher Yes